# Python 3 with Tensorflow on Sagemaker

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I understand the Sagemaker currently does not support Python 3 with Tensorflow (according to this https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/19)

But is it possible to create your own docker container with Python 3 and Tensorflow as is explained here? 
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you create your own Docker container you can use Tensorflow with Python 3. The default Tensorflow Dockerfiles are available [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-containers/tree/master/docker) and you can modify them to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

New script mode containers support python 3 with framework version 1.11. AWS support gave me the impression that python 3 won't be supported on the old tf.estimator style containers.

Comment: Your first and 2nd sentence seem contradictory, or maybe I am only having problems understanding it. Could you please, elaborate a little bit.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/README.rst

Old "method" is now Legacy Mode and the new Script Mode supports python 3.